# Reverse Values Based on Successive Count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series containing only 1's and 0's used as a flag. I'm trying to figure out a good way to count the number of successive repeat values, and if it doesn't meet a threshold, I'd like to reverse them. For instance, if I have less than 5 repeated values in succession, reverse them from 0's to 1's or vice versa.

For example:

```
Flag
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
...
```

Would become:

```
Flag
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
...
```

Comment: Why aren't the last two values flipped?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explicitly state that the series continued. I added ellipses to hopefully better explain that.

Comment: The shortened series makes for a better example anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use `diff().ne(0)` to find the breaks
- Use `cumsum()` to create the groups
- Use `groupby.transform('size')` to count the size of groups
- then flip value with `sub(df.Flag).abs()`

---

```
df.Flag.groupby(
    df.Flag.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
).transform('size').lt(5).sub(df.Flag).abs()

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     0
10    0
Name: Flag, dtype: int64
```

Comment: How do you do this so effortlessly? It took me almost 9 more mins to get anywhere close to this :)

Comment: That's some hefty method chaining. I figured an answer would have to use diff() at its core and some combination of a cumsum() or cumprod(). I'm fairly new to pandas, and I've never even heard of the sub() method before this. This works great.

Answer (score 1):

Just try another way maybe

```
s=df.Flag.diff().ne(0).cumsum().value_counts()
np.where(((s>=5).repeat(s).values),df.Flag,1-df.Flag)
Out[1158]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```